# Font selector style css class not working in IE

Tags: html, css

Hi 
I am having a style class for font tag, If size of the attribute is 1. I am setting the following style.
`font[size = 1]
{
  font-size : small;
}`
It works in FF , chrome but not in IE

Can anyone explain how to make that work in IE?

Comment: Wait, wait wait, you have <font> tag, which you are trying to style?

Answer (score 1):

The font tag is deprecated and should die.
Please use paragraph tags (`<p>`), or span (`<span>`) to style specific text inside a paragraph tag instead.

```
<style type="text/css">
.pClass{
    color:red;
}
.spanClass{
    font-size:small;
}
</style>
<p class="pClass">This is <span class="spanClass">my paragraph</span>, it contains text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<font>` tag [has been deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) and probably won't work as you expect. This is old, old, *old* technology. You should wrap it in a span or other element (depending on usage) with a class:

HTML

```
<span class="myClass">Text example here!</span>
```

CSS

```
.myClass
{
    font-size: small; /*whatever you need*/
}
```

This is supported by all browsers as it's standard CSS.

:)

Answer (score 0):

What if you specify 1pt like `font[size = 1pt] { font-size : small; }`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to not use the font tag at all. It has no semantic meaning.
A better way would be to create a class that holds your desired font style. You can then simply assign this class to any element that you want to apply that style to.

E.g.:
CSS

```
.smallType {
    font-size: small;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="smallType">Hey, look at me! I'm small!</p>
```